# If $g(t,X_t)$ is a martingale, is $X_t$ a semimartingale?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-analysis

Let $(X_t)$ be a continuous stochastic process and $g$ a function such that $g(t,X_t)$ is a martingale with regard to $(X_t)$. Does that mean anything for $X_t$ ? Would that make $(X_t)$ a semimartingale for example ?

Comment: If $g$ is a $C^{1,2}$ diffeomorphism then noting $Z_t= g(t,X_t)$ we are be able to apply Itô to $g^{-1}(Z_t)$ to get $(t,X_t)$ which is then is a semi-martingale and so also $X_t$. Otherwise I think there must be plenty of counterexamples. Maybe there are some additional special cases where your claim might holds beyond the diffeomorphism case but bijection property seems pretty important to me.

Comment: $g$ can be constant, which makes it a martingale, and says nothing about $X$